Network settings for PhpStorm remote development
I am trying to connect PhpStorm remote development to a LAMP container (TurnKey Linux).
It's throwing the following message, and I can't get the remote IDE to connect. I'm certain port forwarding is enabled, but maybe the firewall is blocking something. Any ideas?



This is a platform-wide functionality (not specific to PhpStorm). I've also tagged more generic jetbrains-ide and intellij-idea to cover more  users/people with the experience on this subject.
